# Spring how to load file path of a text file in spring property file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, properties-file

This might be an extremely simple question but I'm really new to spring framework and am just getting my feet wet. I am trying to specify a text file property as part of a bean, the value for which I am specifying from a properties file.

The relevant code is as follows in context.xml file

```
<bean id="myAssembler"
        class="com.pkg.search.myclass.collector.assembler.myAssembler">
        <property name="popularUrlsFileName" value="${POPULAR_URLS_FILE}"/>
    </bean>
```

The POPULAR_URLS_FILE is specified in a .properties file as :

```
POPULAR_URLS_FILE="README.md"
```

But I am getting an error in the xml file as it says it can't find the file with README.md path. What exactly are we supposed to specify as far as the path is concerned for it to find the text file?

Exact error is **"Cannot Resolve File README.md"**

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two things 1) is the README.md on classpath / same folder as of the  .properties file 2) Please post the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, if the file is on the classpath than

```
POPULAR_URLS_FILE="classpath:path/to/README.md"
```

or, if not on the classpath, use the file URL syntax

```
POPULAR_URLS_FILE="file:path/to/README.md"
```